# Compare two files based on first column

Tags: text-processing, awk, comm

I have two files, and I would like to get a new file with only the lines that we have in the first file, but not in the second one. Example:

file1:

```
ID      firstname        lastname
1       John             Wilkens
2       Andrea           Smith
3       Matthew          Freberg
4       Brenda           Something
```

file2:

```
ID      firstname        lastname
1       John             Wilkens
2       Andrea           Willems
3       Jay              Freberg
5       Mike             Hart
```

Output:

```
ID      firstname        lastname
4       Brenda           Something
```

I tried using comm, but that also gives the rows where something was changed, so for example the ID 2 and 3.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: So the comparison is to be made purely based on the ID (i.e. first column of the lines)?

Answer (score 4):

```bsh
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} FNR==1 || !($1 in a)' file2 file1
ID      firstname        lastname
4       Brenda           Something
```

- `NR==FNR{a[$1]; next}` Use first column from `file2` to build array keys

  - `NR` keeps tracks of total number of records read so far, `FNR` has record number only for the current file being read. Thus `NR==FNR` is true only for first file (assuming it isn't empty)
- `FNR==1 || !($1 in a)` for `file1` file, print header line or if the first column isn't found in array `a`
- Use `awk -F'\t' '...'` if your input is tab separated and `awk -F, '...'` if it is comma separated.

If the first file can be empty, use this:

```bsh
awk '!f{a[$1]; next} FNR==1 || !($1 in a)' file2 f=1 file1
```

This will set a flag `f` between the two files.

Answer (score 0):

On a bash command line you can do as follows. Filter the IDs from file2 and look for them in file1 but only at it's beginning of line:

```
$ grep -vf <(< file2 tail -n+2 | grep -Eo '^[^ ]{1,}'|sed 's/.*/^& /') file1
ID      firstname        lastname
4       Brenda           Something
```